# Unable to compile Qt5 examples. QCommandParser not found

Tags: qt5

I wanted to try out Qt5 with it's creator. I wanted to start with examples, so I installed some packages (with apt, also qtcreator package but issued the same with online-installer). 
I am finally able to open examples, but those does not work.

I've tried to find every possible packages of qt in apt that may correspond to examples. Also tried to find package containing corresponding file (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=qcommandlineparser&mode=exactfilename&suite=disco&arch=any). It finds qtbase5-gles-dev, but I cannot install it since it wants me to uninstall a lot of software I need.

```
#include <QCommandLineParser>
#include <QCommandLineOption>
```

Both QCommandLineParser and Option are "file not found".

I'm on Kubuntu 19.04 and Qt Creator 4.8.1 based on Qt 5.12.2 (GCC 8.3.0, 64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

According to this, I was running Qt kit as Qt4 not Qt5:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/916295/building-a-pro-in-qtcreator-gives-qtwidgets-no-such-file-or-directory

> It is possible that the default qt build Kit has been set to qt 4.x rather than qt 5.x when qtcreator was installed. To update this;
>
> qtcreator - options - build & run - Kits - Manual - Desktop (default)
>   - Qt version
>
> Change Qt version from qt 4.x.. to qt 5.x.. in PATH (qt5).

Helped with delay...